# Calling a class method through an object instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railscasts, class-method

Railscasts #4 uses this sample code:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  def self.find_incomplete
    find_all_by_complete(:false, :order => "created_at DESC")
  end
end

class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @tasks = @project.tasks.find_incomplete
  end
end
```

Using `@project.tasks.find_incomplete`, only finds incomplete orders that belong to that specific `Project` instance.

I would expect that call to be equivalent to `Task.find_incomplete`, but it is not. How can that be? How does Rails (or Ruby) now to just invoke that method for those specific `Task`s in that `Project` instance?

Comment: `ActiveRecord` automagically does it for you.

Comment: @ptd, could you explain how it works under the covers?

Comment: Best way to find that out is to look at the code. You'll find out more about the descriptive power of ruby by looking at something like ActiveRecord than you will any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works because scopes of ActiveRecord relations are merged. It's not that `find_incomplete` is running on individual task instances.

`@project.tasks` creates an ActiveRecord scope of the tasks for that project instance and then that scope is still in effect when your `find_incomplete` method is called.

Take a look at the documentation here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Your `find_incomplete` method works in the same way as the `self.published` example in the docs.

Think of the underlying SQL query that would run:

`@project.tasks` would create a `where` condition like `SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project_id = <project_id>`

`find_all_by_complete` then merges in an `and` condition for `complete = 0`

---

I think the other piece of the puzzle that might help is that `@project.tasks` is not just a simple array array of `Task` objects, although it will have been converted to such if you type `project.tasks` in the Rails console. `project.tasks` is actually an Active Record relation object (or more precisely a proxy)
There are a number of reasons and benefits for this but the main 2 are that it allows chaining and it allows the underlying query to be run on demand only if/when needed.

The relation has a sequence of rules for how method calls are delegated, one of which is to call class methods on the class of the associated objects. (the relation knows that it's a relation to `Tasks`)

So you are correct when you wrote `tasks.find_incomplete` is still equal to `Task.find_incomplete` except that when `find_incomplete` is called through `project.tasks` a scope narrowing down to the `project_id` is already in effect.

Comment: Coming from C#, it blows my mind that `foo_instance.class_method` is not equal to `Foo.class_method`. I am still confused though. If `@project.tasks.find_incomplete` is not equal to `Task.find_incomplete`, what is it equal to?

Comment: After your edit, I think I got it. What is happening is `Task.find_incomplete` produces a constraint of `complete = false`, and returns incomplete tasks, and then the scope for the project is added, which is something like `project_id = [ID]`. In the end `tasks.find_incomplete` is still equal to `Task.find_incomplete`. Am I correct?